Issue with Rowspan Values Shifting After Search in HTML Table
I have an HTML table that uses the rowspan attribute. I've added a search feature to the table, but when I search for something like "Washington," it removes the values "Monkey" and "Lion" from the ABC column and replaces them with values from the DEF column. I'm not sure how to fix this. Do you have any advice? Here is my code -


function searchTable() {
  var input, filter, table, tr, td, i, j, txtValue, match;
  input  = document.getElementById("searchInput");
  filter = input.value.toUpperCase();
  table  = document.getElementById("example_full");
  tr     = table.getElementsByTagName("tr");
  match  = false;

  for (i = 1; i < tr.length; i++) {    // Skip the header row
    tr[i].style.display = "none";      // Hide all rows initially
    td                  = tr[i].getElementsByTagName("td");
    for (j = 0; j < td.length; j++) {
      if (td[j]) {
        txtValue = td[j].textContent || td[j].innerText;
        if (txtValue.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1) {
          tr[i].style.display = "";
          match = true;
          break;
        }
      }
    }
  }

  // Show or hide the no match message
  document.getElementById("noMatch").style.display = match ? "none" : "block";
}
.no-match {
  display : none;
  color   : red;
}

th {
  border-left   : 1px solid #dddddd;
  border-top    : 1px solid #dddddd;
  border-bottom : 1px solid #dddddd;
  border-right  : 1px solid #dddddd;
  background-color: darkgray;
}
<input type="text" id="searchInput" placeholder="Search for records..." onkeyup="searchTable()" />
<p id="noMatch" class="no-match">No matching records found</p>

<table id="example_full">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>ABC</th>
      <th>DEF</th>
      <th>GHI</th>
      <th>XXX</th>
      <th>MMM</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td rowspan="4" style=" vertical-align: middle;">MONKEY</td>
      <td>AD123</td>
      <td>434SDD</td>
      <td>DFDDFF</td>
      <td>FDFFD</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>LEMON</td>
      <td>&#160;</td>
      <td>FDFGGF</td>
      <td>DFFDF</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>&#160;</td>
      <td>&#160;</td>
      <td>FDDFF</td>
      <td>Edison</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>FDDFFDF</td>
      <td>&#160;</td>
      <td>East</td>
      <td>Washington</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td rowspan="3" style=" background-color: #F9F9F9; vertical-align: middle;">LION</td>
      <td>GFFG</td>
      <td>FGFGG</td>
      <td>FGFG</td>
      <td>FGGFGFG</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>&#160;</td>
      <td>&#160;</td>
      <td>FGHGH</td>
      <td>DDDFF</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td></td>
      <td>test2</td>
      <td>FFGGFH</td>
      <td>Washington</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>




The row with "MONKEY" is being hidden.  When searching for "Washington" only one row is shown, and that row has only 4 columns.  (This is probably a good time to start familiarizing yourself with your browser's debugging tools.  Particularly the DOM explorer which shows you the current state of the document, as well as the script debugger which allows you to step through your code and observe the exact changes it's making.)

Do you need to use the rowspan?  What if you just repeat the Monkey value for the first 4 rows and the Lion value for the last 3 rows.  If you did that then your search code and display would work appropriately.  @mplungjan is correct, otherwise it gets quite tricky to manage when a  needs to added and removed as you search.

We just gave you a great way. So now you want to show the whole set of rows if the text is found in cells that are part of a rowspan? So each row that has a cell with filter text in it has to know it is part of a rowspan and show the row that has the rowspan too?

Per your comment 'Is there a way to still show the value for column ABC if I search "Lemon", here is a solution that will create and delete cells and labels as needed.  I tried to add some basic comments to the js code to help explain what is going on.


function searchTable() {
  var input, filter, table, tr, th, td, i, j, txtValue, match, rowSpan, rowSpanData;
   input  = document.getElementById("searchInput");
   filter = input.value.toUpperCase();
   table  = document.getElementById("example_full");
   tr     = table.getElementsByTagName("tr");
   th     = table.getElementsByTagName("th");
   match  = false;

  rowSpan = 1;
  rowSpanData = '';

  for (i = 1; i < tr.length; i++) {    // Skip the header row
    tr[i].style.display = "none";      // Hide all rows initially
    td                  = tr[i].getElementsByTagName("td");
    //console.log("TD Length = " + td.length);
    
    //Loop through the cells
    for (j = 0; j < td.length; j++) {

    if (td[j]) {
    
    if(filter!="") {
        if(j==0 && td.length == th.length){
          rowSpanData = td[j].innerHTML;
        }
        
        //If there is a match 
        txtValue = td[j].textContent || td[j].innerText;
        if (txtValue.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1) {
           
             tr[i].style.display = "";
             //match boolean to be used for display of match message at end of fucntion
             match = true;
           

          if (td.length == th.length && td[0].hasAttribute("rowspan") && td[0].getAttribute("rowspan") != 1) {
            td[0].setAttribute("originalRowSpan", td[0].getAttribute("rowspan"));
            td[0].setAttribute("rowspan", 1);
          }
          if(td.length < th.length){
             var newCell = tr[i].insertCell(0);
             newCell.classList.add("removeMe");
             newCell.innerHTML= rowSpanData;
          }
          // skip to the next row
          continue;
        } //end of match section

        } else {
          tr[i].style.display = "";
            if(td[j].hasAttribute("rowspan")){
              td[j].setAttribute("rowspan", td[j].getAttribute("originalRowSpan"));
            } else if(td[j].classList.contains("removeMe")){
              tr[i].deleteCell(0);
            }
        }
          
      } 
    } // end of cell loop
  } // end of row loop

  // Show or hide the no match message
  document.getElementById("noMatch").style.display = match ? "none" : "block";
}
.no-match {
  display : none;
  color   : red;
}

th {
  border-left   : 1px solid #dddddd;
  border-top    : 1px solid #dddddd;
  border-bottom : 1px solid #dddddd;
  border-right  : 1px solid #dddddd;
  background-color: darkgray;
}
<input type="text" id="searchInput" placeholder="Search for records..." onkeyup="searchTable()" />
<p id="noMatch" class="no-match">No matching records found</p>

<table id="example_full">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>ABC</th>
      <th>DEF</th>
      <th>GHI</th>
      <th>XXX</th>
      <th>MMM</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td rowspan="4" style=" vertical-align: middle;">MONKEY</td>
      <td>AD123</td>
      <td>434SDD</td>
      <td>DFDDFF</td>
      <td>FDFFD</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>LEMON</td>
      <td>&#160;</td>
      <td>FDFGGF</td>
      <td>DFFDF</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>&#160;</td>
      <td>&#160;</td>
      <td>FDDFF</td>
      <td>Edison</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>FDDFFDF</td>
      <td>&#160;</td>
      <td>East</td>
      <td>Washington</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td rowspan="3" style=" background-color: #F9F9F9; vertical-align: middle;">LION</td>
      <td>GFFG</td>
      <td>FGFGG</td>
      <td>FGFG</td>
      <td>FGGFGFG</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>&#160;</td>
      <td>&#160;</td>
      <td>FGHGH</td>
      <td>DDDFF</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td></td>
      <td>test2</td>
      <td>FFGGFH</td>
      <td>Washington</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>




Works great, thankyou so much

It's good when LEMON is alone))

Use tr { visibility: collapse; } instead of tr { display: none; }:


document.getElementById('search-input').addEventListener('keyup', searchTable);

function searchTable() {
  const filter = this.value.toUpperCase();
  let isMatch = false;

  const tbody = document.querySelector('#example_full tbody');
  const noMatch = document.getElementById('no-match');

  if (!filter) {
    tbody.querySelectorAll('tr').forEach(tr => {
      tr.classList.remove('collapse', 'hidden');
    });
    noMatch.classList.remove('active');
    return;
  }

  let rowspanEndIndex = 0;

  tbody.querySelectorAll('tr').forEach((tr, index) => {
    tr.classList.add('collapse');
    tr.classList.remove('hidden');

    if (rowspanEndIndex === index) {
      rowspanEndIndex = 0;
    }
    tr.querySelectorAll('td').forEach(td => {
      td.removeAttribute('hidden');
      const rowspan = td.getAttribute('rowspan');
      if (rowspan) {
        rowspanEndIndex = index + Number(rowspan);
      }
      if (td.textContent && td.textContent.toUpperCase().includes(filter)) {
        tr.classList.remove('collapse');
        isMatch = true;
      }
    });
    if (rowspanEndIndex) {
      tr.setAttribute('data-group', rowspanEndIndex);
    }
  });
  document
    .querySelectorAll('#example_full tbody tr:has([rowspan])')
    .forEach(tr => {
      const group = tr.getAttribute('data-group');
      const trs = tbody.querySelectorAll(`tr[data-group="${group}"]`).length;
      const collapseTrs = tbody.querySelectorAll(
        `tr[data-group="${group}"].collapse`,
      ).length;
      if (trs !== collapseTrs) {
        tr.classList.remove('collapse');
        tr.querySelectorAll('td:not([rowspan])').forEach(td =>
          td.setAttribute('hidden', true),
        );
      }
    });
  noMatch.classList.toggle('active', !isMatch);
}
.no-match {
  color: red;
  &:not(.active) {
    display: none;
  }
}

table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

td,
th {
  padding: 2px 8px;
}

th {
  border: 1px solid #dddddd;
  background-color: darkgray;
}

tr.collapse {
  visibility: collapse;
}
<input
  type="text"
  id="search-input"
  placeholder="Search for records..."
/>
<p
  id="no-match"
  class="no-match"
>
  No matching records found
</p>

<table id="example_full">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>ABC</th>
      <th>DEF</th>
      <th>GHI</th>
      <th>XXX</th>
      <th>MMM</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td
        rowspan="4"
        style="vertical-align: middle"
      >
        MONKEY
      </td>
      <td>AD123</td>
      <td>434SDD</td>
      <td>DFDDFF</td>
      <td>FDFFD</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>LEMON</td>
      <td>&#160;</td>
      <td>FDFGGF</td>
      <td>DFFDF</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>&#160;</td>
      <td>&#160;</td>
      <td>FDDFF</td>
      <td>Edison</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>FDDFFDF</td>
      <td>&#160;</td>
      <td>East</td>
      <td>LEMON</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>One tr</td>
      <td>&#160;</td>
      <td>LEMON</td>
      <td>DDDFF</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td
        rowspan="3"
        style="background-color: #f9f9f9; vertical-align: middle"
      >
        LION
      </td>
      <td>GFFG</td>
      <td>FGFGG</td>
      <td>FGFG</td>
      <td>FGGFGFG</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>&#160;</td>
      <td>&#160;</td>
      <td>FGHGH</td>
      <td>DDDFF</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td></td>
      <td>test2</td>
      <td>FFGGFH</td>
      <td>Washington</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>




Excellent. Well done. Damn you! ;)

Great, thank you so much. This works well. Is there a way to still show the value for column ABC if I search "Lemon". It should show Monkey under column ABC. Thanks.

Make sure each row has 5 cells. In your case you collapse to 4 cells on rows that do not have the rowspan
Here is a more streamlined version using imhvost's suggestion to collapse the visibility instead of display:none/hidden


const input = document.getElementById("searchInput");
const noMatch = document.getElementById("noMatch");
const rows = document.querySelectorAll("#example_full tbody tr");
const searchTable = () => {
  let filter = input.value.toUpperCase(),
  match = false;
  rows.forEach(row => {
    let found = filter && Array.from(row.querySelectorAll('td')).some(td => td.textContent.toUpperCase().includes(filter));
    row.style.visibility = filter && !found ? 'collapse' : 'visible';
    if (found) match = true; // set if any hit
  });  
  // Show or hide the no match message
   noMatch.hidden = !filter || (filter && match);
}
input.addEventListener('input',searchTable);
.no-match {
  color: red;
}

th {
  border-left: 1px solid #dddddd;
  border-top: 1px solid #dddddd;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #dddddd;
  border-right: 1px solid #dddddd;
  background-color: darkgray;
}
<input type="text" id="searchInput" placeholder="Search for records..." />
<p id="noMatch" hidden class="no-match">No matching records found</p>

<table id="example_full">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>ABC</th>
      <th>DEF</th>
      <th>GHI</th>
      <th>XXX</th>
      <th>MMM</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td rowspan="4" style=" vertical-align: middle;">MONKEY</td>
      <td>AD123</td>
      <td>434SDD</td>
      <td>DFDDFF</td>
      <td>FDFFD</td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td>LEMON</td>
      <td>&#160;</td>
      <td>FDFGGF</td>
      <td>DFFDF</td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td>&#160;</td>
      <td>&#160;</td>
      <td>FDDFF</td>
      <td>Edison</td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td>FDDFFDF</td>
      <td>&#160;</td>
      <td>East</td>
      <td>Washington</td>
    </tr>



    <tr>
      <td rowspan="3" style=" background-color: #F9F9F9; vertical-align: middle;">LION</td>
      <td>GFFG</td>
      <td>FGFGG</td>
      <td>FGFG</td>
      <td>FGGFGFG</td>
    </tr>



    <tr>
      <td>&#160;</td>
      <td>&#160;</td>
      <td>FGHGH</td>
      <td>DDDFF</td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td></td>
      <td>test2</td>
      <td>FFGGFH</td>
      <td>Washington</td>
    </tr>

  </tbody>
</table>




Thank you, but I am not seeing much difference. If I search for Washington, the columns still shift. Am I missing something?

No. It is the rowspan that ruins it

No so easy todo, but:

Table <TR> element has an hidden property, to show / hide entire row.
I also use .rows and .cells properties



const 
  inSearch  = document.querySelector('#search-input')
, msg_match = document.querySelector('#match-msg')
, expl_TB   = document.querySelector('#example_full tbody')
  ;
function searchTable()
  {
  const 
    inFind = inSearch.value.trim()
  , inRgx  = new RegExp( inFind, 'gi')
    ;
  expl_TB.querySelectorAll('td.matched').forEach( td => td.classList.remove('matched'));
  expl_TB.querySelectorAll('tr')        .forEach( tr => tr.hidden = false );

  if ( inFind === '' )  // input is empty....
    {
    inSearch.value = '';
    msg_match.classList.remove('noVisible'); 
    return;
    }

  // find process...
  let
    matchingCount = 0
  , rowParentIdxZ = 0
  , rowParentLast = 0
  , rowShowed     = new Set()
    ;

  for (let tr of expl_TB.rows )
    {
    let parent = getParentIdxZ( tr );

    for (let td of tr.cells)   // Find matching cells...
      {
      if (inRgx.test(td.textContent ))
        {
        matchingCount++;
        td.classList.add('matched');
        rowShowed.add(parent);
        }
      }
    }

  if ( matchingCount === 0)  // no cells matching
    {
    msg_match.classList.remove('noVisible'); 
    return;
    }

  msg_match.classList.add('noVisible'); 

  for (let tr of expl_TB.rows ) // hide unmatched rows...
    {
    tr.hidden = !rowShowed.has( getParentIdxZ( tr ) );
    }

  function getParentIdxZ( tr )  // sub function...
    {
    let idxZ = tr.rowIndex -1;  // use indexing where first index value is Zero;

    if (tr.cells[0].rowSpan > 1 )
      {
      rowParentIdxZ = idxZ
      rowParentLast = idxZ + tr.cells[0].rowSpan; 
      }
    return (idxZ < rowParentLast) ? rowParentIdxZ : idxZ;
    }
  }
body {
  font-family     : Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  font-size       : 14px;
  }
table {
  background      : darkblue;
  border-collapse : separate;
  border-spacing  : 1px;
  }
th {
  background-color : #7fccff;
  padding          : .4em .6em ;
  }
td {
  background-color : whitesmoke;
  padding          : .6em .4em;
  }
.matched {
  color      : red;
  background : lightgreen;
  }
#match-msg {
  margin-top    : 0.3em;
  margin-bottom : 1em;
  padding-left  : 2em;
  color         : darkblue;
  }
.noVisible {
  visibility : hidden;
  }
<input  id="search-input" type="text" placeholder="Search for records..." onkeyup="searchTable()" />
<p id="match-msg" >No matching records found</p>

<table id="example_full">
  <thead>
    <tr> <th>ABC</th><th>DEF</th><th>GHI</th><th>XXX</th><th>MMM</th> </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr><td rowspan="4">MONKEY</td><td>AD123</td><td>434SDD</td><td>DFDDFF</td><td>FDFFD</td> </tr>
    <tr><td>LEMON</td><td>&#160;</td><td>FDFGGF</td><td>DFFDF</td> </tr>
    <tr><td>&#160;</td><td>&#160;</td><td>FDDFF</td><td>Edison</td> </tr>
    <tr><td>FDDFFDF</td><td>&#160;</td><td>East</td><td>Washington</td> </tr>

    <tr><td>a</td><td>Mister</td><td>Jojo</td><td>d</td><td>e</td> </tr>

    <tr><td rowspan="3">LION</td><td>GFFG</td><td>FGFGG</td><td>FGFG</td><td>FGGFGFG</td> </tr>
    <tr><td>&#160;</td><td>&#160;</td><td>FGHGH</td><td>DDDFF</td> </tr>
    <tr><td></td><td>test2</td><td>FFGGFH</td><td>Washington</td> </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>



